# Adding Bootstrap Css in reactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap in React. Bootstrap button and grid are working but CSS for bootstrap is not showing up. Are there any steps to add bootstrap CSS separately?

Comment: read this article https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-react-a354715d1121 and delete your question if you dont want to get down votes for that , is it duplicated

Comment: Thanks for the Blog @a_m_dev but Nothing is duplicated.

Comment: @alekhsharma, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First refer this, [Bootstrap webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/)

This is one way of using bootstrap in reactjs projects.

The advantage of this is that u get access to latest bootstrap css.

The disadvantage of using this is its complicated to use jquery plugins in reactjs. Hovewr if you are only interested in css, then its perfect.

Using this u can directly use bootstrap classes from documentation and get more control.
Just use `className` instead of `class`

If u want simple setup , then u can use reactstrap [link](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

Other frameworks include react-bootstrap [link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks @GautamNaik, it completed my requirement in multiple ways.